# Modify PYTHONPATH via Ansible for supervisorctl managed Python application

Tags: django, ansible, supervisord

I am provisioning a server with a Django Stack via Ansible and getting the app from bitbucket, I am using https://github.com/jcalazan/ansible-django-stack, but I have had to tweak it a bit in order to make it work with a private bitbucket repo.

Now it's authenticating correctly but giving me the following error

> failed: [default] => {"failed": true} msg: youtubeadl: ERROR (not
>   running) youtubeadl: ERROR (abnormal termination)

When performing this task:

```
- name: Restart Supervisor
  supervisorctl: name={{ application_name }} state=restarted
```

Reading [gunicorn ERROR (abnormal termination)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21189525/gunicorn-error-abnormal-termination), I would like to add the project to the PYTHONPATH, any ideas how to approach this with an Ansible task, or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Since it's supervisor that starts your program, I think it's more a supervisor issue. If you [program] definition, you should use "environement" to set your PYTHONPATH: http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings

Answer (score 6):

`PYTHONPATH` is just another environment variable, so you can use the best practices [explained in the FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-can-i-set-the-path-or-any-other-environment-variable-for-a-task-or-entire-playbook). If it's only needed for the one task, it'd  look something like:

```
- name: Restart Supervisor
  supervisorctl: name={{ application_name }} state=restarted
  environment:
      PYTHONPATH: "{{ ansible_env.PYTHONPATH }}:/my/path"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something changed. I tried this answer above, but doesn't works. After some digging, and trying:

```
- name: Restart Supervisor
  supervisorctl: name={{ application_name }} state=restarted
  environment:
      PYTHONPATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/my/path"
```

This should be correct answer.